# Flexbox row/columns equal height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a row with two columns, both 50%. The left one has an image, the right one text. My html:

```css
.row{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  align-items:center;
}

.cell1, .cell2{
  width:50%;
}

.cell2 {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="cell1"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/450x450" ></div>
    <div class="cell2">Cell 2</div>
</div>
```

Now I want the background of cell2 to be green and need cell2 to be the same height as cell1, and I know I can achieve it by giving the row this background, but how do I make only cell2's background be green (and have the same height as cell1)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keep the default alignment on the main container `stretch` so that both will have the same height then align the content inside `cell2`:

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}

.cell1,
.cell2 {
  width: 50%;
}

.cell2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="cell1"><img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200?image=0" ></div>
  <div class="cell2">some text here</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `align-items: center;` from `row` and added in  `cell2` with `display:flex`

```css
.row{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;  
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.cell1, .cell2{
  width:50%;
  display:flex;
}
.cell1 img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.cell2 {
  background: green;
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="cell1"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/450x450" ></div>
    <div class="cell2">Cell 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked, but therer is a problem with the responsiveness. At a certain point when the text becomes too long the image gets stretched in height.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.row{
  display:flex;
/*   flex-direction:row; */
/*   align-items:center; */ 
}
.cell1, .cell2{
  width: 50%;
}
.cell1 img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}
.cell2 {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="cell1"><img src="https://image.ibb.co/jqzDOe/111.jpg"></div>
    <div class="cell2">Cell 2</div>
</div>
```